# explode list to another list at space characters

Tags: python

I'm wondering, how can I explode a lists at it's elements at space charachters to another list?

For exaple, the list contains these elements:

```
['John', 'House', '23 4500', 'grass', '542 3256']
```

to

```
['John', 'House', '23', '4500', 'grass', '542', '3256']
```

Comment: Do you mean `["John", "House", "23 4500", "grass", "542 3256"]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> L = ['John', 'House', '23 4500', 'grass', '542 3256']
>>> [y for x in L for y in x.split()]
['John', 'House', '23', '4500', 'grass', '542', '3256']
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, L)))
['John', 'House', '23', '4500', 'grass', '542', '3256']
```

Comment: This soloution ended up being the best for me. Thank You all for Your help!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it:

```
>>> l = ['John', 'House', '23 4500', 'grass', '542 3256'];
>>> m = ' '.join(l).split()
['John', 'House', '23', '4500', 'grass', '542', '3256']
```